# Sum cells in a row from columns with numbers given in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum values in a row, but only for specific column numbers (or headers) which are listed elsewhere and are not constant.

It might be some range, or even better one cell with array containing column numbers. In either case not whole range or array will be always fully populated.
Is this even possible without using VBA?

If there's no way to avoid VBA I can give it a shot.

[image: Example]

Comment: Outcome would be sum of cells in a row from columns number 2 and 4 for SUM 1, 1+3+4 for SUM 2 etx

Comment: Look into indirect function, or address function

Comment: This is simple example, I have 10-30 sums and 10-30 columns from which I want to sum chosen values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following:

[image]

Formula in `H8`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COLUMN($B8:$G8)=H$2:H$5+1)*$B8:$G8)
```

It's actually simple in this case since the second array is already transposed. Keep that in mind if you want to do this in any other way.